# Marquee with navigation arrows HTML

Tags: html, marquee, navigationcontroller

I have created a Marquee in my HTML with

```
<marquee behavior="alternate" scrollamount="1" width="400">
</marquee>
```

And it's working fine.

But I would like to add arrows to this marquee so allow the user to the contents to move `left/right` faster.

I've been attempting to use scroll bars but doesn't seem like the best solution as the scroll width will have to be smaller than marquee width for it to work.

Any solutions.

Comment: Firstly, do you mean a scrolling text marquee? These are now deprecated.

Secondly, post your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) on how to ask questions.

Comment: hi mick 

my marquee is for thumbnail images to automatically scroll in a small box:

<marquee behavior="alternate" scrollamount="1" width="400">
<img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-180" /></a>   
<img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-182"/></a>  
<img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-180"/></a>   
<img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-183"/></a></marquee>
it does work, but my question is can i add arrows to the left and right of this box and allow the server to scroll faster than the marquee left or right if they wish

Answer (score 1):

Are you just using plain HTML, or can you use Javascript / jQuery? If so, something like this might be helpful:

http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

That's just from a quick Google, so there might be prettier jQuery solutions out there.

Comment: I'm just using plain HTML and CSS in Wordpress
Sadly my skills ends here, I've never used javascript or jquery:( 

can this not be done in HTML or CSS

Comment: Then I think you might be stuck. Also, most people generally dislike marquees, so you might be better off finding a different solution, if possible.

Comment: i see... i agree with the dislike of marquees, but my boss likes it :(  Thanks very much any way ^_^